# Name and cite specific figures/results of related work

Tags: publications, citations, citation-style

Currently I am writing a paper and would like to cite specific things in the *related work* section of other papers.

For example:

> In figure 4 in *name of the related work* [\cite] you can see distortions after applying equation 8 of [\cite]. XYZ et. al. have stated this appears due to ...

Would this be legit?

Basically I do not need the most stuff out of this paper which I want to cite, just this one figure, equation and their explanation why this happened. The main research in that paper is irrelevant for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's quite normal to site specific parts of a reference. Pointing at a figure is very much like citing a large block of text. It is legitimate.